# Why is the work done on a particle in a magnetic field zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, work

In the image below, the negative charged particle with a velocity v experiences of force in a magnetic field F perpendicular to the velocity v. The work done on the particle is said to be 0, but why? Shouldn't the work done be Fcos(theta)xdisplacement vector where theta is the angle between the Force and the displacement vector> Or the dot product between the displacement vector and the force vector? If the force is now increased dramatically, we would expect the particle to follow an elipsis, at those conditions it couldn't be argued that no work has been done on the particle anymore...

[image]

[image]

Comment: You know that the displacement vector for $\theta$ also points into/out of the page too right? In the same vein as how $\omega$ in this case is directed into the page here.

Comment: @yogi The lorenz force formula reads $f=q\vec E + q \vec v \times \vec B$ for a point charge q. $dw=f\cdot d \vec r=f\cdot \vec v dt = q\vec E \cdot \vec v dt + q (\vec v \times \vec B)\cdot v dt$, now say theres somehow no electric field, and only magnetic field. can you tell what happens to the 2nd term above?

Comment: There might be an implicit condition of a static magnetic field. Also this sounds like when people ask why 90 degree acceleration does no work, like in a free spinning wheel so you might want to search those answers.

Comment: *"Shouldn't the work done be Fcos(theta)xdisplacement vector..."* Yes. And cos(theta) is zero, so the work is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Lorentz force acting on a charged particle reads $\mathbf{F} = q \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}$, and thus it is always orthogonal to the velocity. The work involves the dot product of the force and the elementary displacement (aligned with velocity) and thus the work is zero. Explicitly, the work of Lorentz force reads
\begin{equation}
   W = \int \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{r} = \int \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{v} dt = \int q \underbrace{\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{v}}_{=0} dt
\end{equation}

Comment: But isn't it an assumption that the displacement of the particle is in the same direction as the tangential velocity vector. I've added an image to the question. The force on the particle must accelerate the particle in the direction of the force. It applies a value of v onto the particle. Therefor,  if we calculate the resultant vector of velocity of the tangential velocity and the velocity contributed by the force. This should be the displacement direction?

Comment: Okay, but can you explain why the direction of the particle changes if the particle does not move in the direction of the force?

Comment: acceleration is in the direction of the force, not velocity. As an example, in a uniform circular motion (the same that the charged particle in a uniform magnetic field describes) the velocity is tangential to the circular trajectory, while the acceleration always points towards the center of the cirlce

Comment: And acceleration is the change in velocity per unit time. It looks like you need to review Kinematics. You've just given another example of the same system yet have not explain why the particle changes direction if it infact does not in the direction of the force.

Answer (score 1):

If you take in mind that :
$\vec{W}=\int{d\vec{W}}=\int{F.dx.cos(\theta)}$ for dx is the differential displacement.
therefore you see in each point the displacement is perpendicular to the force applied, so $\theta=90$ and $cos(\theta)=0$ .since we know integral is a form of summation, summation of 0s will be zero
also when the particle goes a full round on the circle, the displacement is equal to $0$. so in one revolve, we can say work done on the particle is zero with two explanations.